# How does the FileInputStream class knows the offset when the read method is called again and again?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, java-io, fileinputstream

Here I am using FileInputStream class to read data from input.txt. `read` method is called twice. How does the inputStream object know that it has to read the second character when the read method is called the second time? I mean does inputStream object maintain the offset?

```
package streams;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        read();
    }

    private static void read() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/input.txt");
        int data;
        data = inputStream.read();
        System.out.println(data);
        data = inputStream.read();
        System.out.println(data);
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't. The operating system does.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the the `FileInputStream` keeps a reference to a some OS-file handle on which is operates the `read` method. This file-handle will maintain the offset in the file and will forward it by howerver many bytes were read.

Comment: I do not see any offset property. Also the `read` method, in turn, calls native method read0. Can you please help me with how the offset is maintained?

Comment: @user3807454 As you correctly observed is the `read` method is not implemented in java-code but calls to some native code. This is because file handling is differend on different OSs and therefore handled by the OS-Kernel. If you create a new `FileInputStream` object the JVM will ask the kernel to open the file and it will create a file-handle that maintains the offset in the file. So the offset in the file is not maintained by the JVM but the OS. 
But I don't know why the class `FileInputStream` does not provide a method to retrieve or the the offset.

Comment: @Ackdari most likely because it isn't very useful. In most streams there is no (relevant) concept of offset (you could have infinite generated streams for example), and even with a file stream it's the data you're interested in, not the positions. If you're interested in offsets, then `RandomAccessFile` is more relevant.

Comment: @Ackdan Your answer clearly states that 'the `FileInputStream` keeps the offset and updates it`, while your comment states exactly the opposite. Make up your mind.

Comment: @Kayaman actually, you *can* query the position of a `FileInputStream`, if the compile-time type of the variable is `FileInputStream` or when you cast the object appropriately. Just use `fileInputStream.getChannel().position()`. Even setting the position to an absolute value is possible via `getChannel()`.

Comment: @Holger ah yes, the `FileChannel` provides a backdoor to things that the simple `InputStream` abstraction doesn't (e.g. seeking).

Comment: @Kayaman well, you can do relative seek operations on a `FileInputStream` directly via `skip`, even backwards, but you’d need to remember the current position yourself to use it to get to an absolute position.

Comment: @Holger ah indeed, although this is a bit quirky since Java 7 didn't permit [backwards skip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip(long)), but Java 8 [does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip-long-). I expected there to be changes because of `Channel`, but that's a 1.4 introduction, so this isn't even related to that.

Comment: @Kayaman a typical case of “adapting the spec because the impl does something different”. I just checked it; even with JDK 6, backward skipping works. Perhaps, your thought about a change with the `getChannel()` introduction was correct, but the change was not documented by that time (1.4).